# Laravel makeHidden (how to use)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3, and currently working on models.

I have the following code:

```
$result = TheEpisode::find($id)->with('TheParts')->take(1)->get()->each(function ($item) {
      $item->TheParts->makeHidden("title");
});
```

The purpose of this code is to display all the data from `TheEpisode` and `TheParts`, but exclude the title from there.

Can this be improved, like not using a loop to exclude the title attribute?

Answer (score 1):

no need to loop as you are using find method and find method always give single result

```
$result = TheEpisode::find($id);
$result->TheParts->makeHidden("title");
dd($result->toArray());
```

Comment: TheParts has multiple values, are you sure makeHidden will work on multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is important to note that, you are making 2 different queries by doing something like `find($id)->with(...)`

1. The reason behind this is -> `find($id)` performs the `SELECT * FROM WHERE ID = ...` query and the object of model is returned.
2. Now once again, after getting $model you are performing the `with()` function of the query builder which finally makes another query.

For more optimization, please prefer the below code.

```
$item = TheEpisode::with('TheParts')->find($id);

$item->TheParts->transform(function($part) {
  $part->makeHidden('title');
  return $part;
});
```

1. Line 1 performs only 1 query which returns the model.
2. When you do `$item->TheParts`, based on your relation, you'll get a collection/model. Since **An episode** can have **multiple parts**, I am going to consider it a `HasMany` relation and therefore you get a collection.
3. Finally, you perform `transform` (documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-transform)) which modifies the collection itself.